# How to use parameter and requests header in Python API with Postgresql?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am working on my project using PostgreSQL. I want to use get request with "parameters" and "requests-header".

Parameter = "gridname"
requests-header = "ownerid"

Here is my code that I am using with Python Tornado framework. For creating the table, I am using SQLAlchemy and for fetching data from PostgreSQL, use Raw SQL.

```
db_string = "postgres://user:PWD@**.**.**.***:####/db_demo"

Base = declarative_base()
db = create_engine(db_string)

class DBFetch(RequestHandler):
    def get(self, gridname):  
        ownerid_var = self.request.headers["ownerid"]
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=db) 
        session = Session()
        Base.metadata.create_all(db)

        result = []
        record = db.execute("SELECT name, columndata, gridname, ownerid, issystem, ispublic, isactive, createdby, createdat, modifiedat, modifiedby
                       FROM col.layout WHERE (ispublic=1 OR (ispublic=0 AND ownerid=?)) AND (gridname=? AND isactive=1)", (ownerid_var,gridname))

        for row in record:
            result.append(row)

        result_json = json.dumps(result)
        self.write(result_json)
        self.finish()
        session.close()

def make_app():
    urls = [("/webcustomization/layouts/(.*)", DBFetch)]
    return Application(urls)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(3000)
    IOLoop.instance().start()
```

But I am running my code on Postman and insert input for request header(ownerid) = 3, then getting below error :

```
(psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction) operator does not exist: character varying =?
LINE 1: ...                  (ispublic=0 AND ownerid::varchar=?)) AND (...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type. You might need to add an explicit type cast.

[SQL: SELECT name, columndata, gridname, ownerid, issystem, ispublic, isactive,                            createdby, createdat, modifiedat, modifiedby                            FROM col.layout WHERE (ispublic=1 OR                             (ispublic=0 AND ownerid::varchar=?)) AND (gridname=? AND isactive=1)]
[parameters: ('3', 'RT')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

What should I have to do, to fetch the data? Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Psycopg2 uses %s instead of ?:

```
record = db.execute("SELECT name, columndata, gridname, ownerid, issystem, ispublic, isactive, createdby, createdat, modifiedat, modifiedby
                       FROM col.layout WHERE (ispublic=1 OR (ispublic=0 AND ownerid=%s)) AND (gridname=%s AND isactive=1)", (ownerid_var,gridname))
```

Comment: one more thing, I am able to get the data now but I am getting this error.    File "C:\Users\mpal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\tornado\httputil.py", line 239, in __getitem__
    return self._dict[_normalized_headers[name]]
KeyError: 'Ownerid'